Defintion of distributions why not define with complex conjugate
For a complex valued locally integrable function $f$ on an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, I saw many sources defined distribution induced by $f$ as $\phi \mapsto \int f\phi \, dx$.

If $\phi$ is complex valued, why not (or would it be better to) define the distribution induced by $f$ as $\phi \mapsto \int \phi\overline{f} \, dx$? I felt this definition would be more natural as when we write duality bracket such as $\langle \phi,f \rangle$ it means the same as inner product when $f\in L^{2}(U)$

Similarly, for a fourier transform of a tempered distribution $T$, by similar manner, I'm not sure why we define it as $\hat{T}(\phi)=T(\hat{\phi})$, instead of $\hat{T}(\phi)=T(\check{\phi})$. This other definition would also concord with the Plancheral Theorem which states for $f,g \in L^{2}$. $\langle \hat{f},\hat{g} \rangle = \langle f, g \rangle$

Edit: It seems Terence Tao did it this way. Not sure why other sources such as Folland's Real Analysis or Duoandikoetxea's Fourier Analysis don't. I think Folland considered complex valued functions as well.

To begin with, the mapping $\phi \rightarrow \int f\overline{\phi}dx$ is conjugate-linear, so it is not even a distribution.

@Matsmir Thank you. I just looked up Tao's epsilon of room notes a moment ago. Now I see why Tao defined distribution induced $f$ by as $\phi \mapsto \int \phi \overline{f} , dx$. Tao actually did what I said for Fourier transform. Not sure why other people don't do it in this way

I suppose there was a typo, and conjugation initially was meant to be over $f$. Now, I think, it is a matter of taste. I can give a reason to not put conjugation there: with it the mapping from the function $f$ to the corresponding distribution becomes conjugate-linear. It does not affect theory in any significant way, but now you need to worry about conjugated scalars in formulas. On the other hand, it simplifies notation when working with $L_2$. Whatever suites you best...

@Matsmir I see. Yeah I agree with you, but in the case of Fourier transform, I don't know why one would not do Tao's version, it is quite confusing in the other way.

Yes, this issue has annoyed me for many years. :) As you already know, and as in comments, some things might be simpler if the imbedding $f\to u_f$ of test functions to distributions by $u_f(g)=\int f\cdot g$ had a conjugation on one or the other of $f$ and/or $g$.
As it turns out, we "can't have everything" here. Namely, if in the defn we use $\overline{f}$, then the map is not complex-linear in $f$. If we use $\overline{g}$, then $\mu_f$ is not in the complex-linear dual. (Ok, yes, maybe we could start wrangling about complex-linearity versus ... of duals...)
By this point, not to mention that there's a huge accumulation of convention... I don't think there's a way to avoid the NOT-one-size-fits-all "problem". Much as with the "annoying" issue of "where the $2\pi$ goes in Fourier transforms. :)
